# select date field, returning DISTANT_FUTURE in place of null

Tags: mysql, sql

In SQL (mysql dialect), how can I coalesce a date field to return DISTANT_FUTURE or DISTANT_PAST in place of null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to wrap your nullable date field as follows:

```
SELECT
coalesce(nullableDate,date_add(curdate(), interval 100 year)) as thedate
FROM MyTable
```

You can replace the `100` with a figure of your own choosing, including a negative figure for "distant past".